# Replacing image src with input hidden value using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have below input hidden with value ="/fr/images/findacourse_logo_tcm10-268.gif".

```
<input type="hidden" id="Qt_Email_Image" value="/fr/images/findacourse_logo_tcm10-268.gif"/>
```

I have another input image below with src = "/images/quote/Quote_Email_Button.JPG"

```
<tr>
    <td>
         </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="">
        <input type="image" border="0" alt="Email me this quote " src="/images/quote/Quote_Email_Button.JPG" id="Quote_btnEmail" name="Quote:btnEmail"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want at runtime the input image src gets replaced with above input hidden value and will show above image instead of image link in src. So that my above html becomes

```
<tr>
    <td>
         </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="">
        <input type="image" border="0" alt="Email me this quote " src="/fr/images/findacourse_logo_tcm10-268.gif" id="Quote_btnEmail" name="Quote:btnEmail"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to use Jquery for above solution, please suggest!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you replace image like this:

```
$('#Quote_btnEmail').attr('src', $('#Qt_Email_Image').attr('value'))
```

Then your current image "Quote Email Button.JPG" is being removed, then new image "findacourse logo tcm10-268.gif" is loaded and then shown. So if the loading part takes a while, then the user will see a flicker.

To avoid that, you can load your "findacourse logo tcm10-268.gif" first and then instantly show it to the user:

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).load( function () {
    $('#Quote_btnEmail').attr('src', img.src);
});
img.src = $('#Qt_Email_Image').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Quote_btnEmail').attr('src', $('#Qt_Email_Image').val());
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$('#Quote_btnEmail').attr('src', $('#Qt_Email_Image').attr('value'))
```

Comment: I think that `$.attr('value')` is not cross browser.

Comment: attr('value') is perfectly cross-browser supported, as a matter of fact, if the subject is not an options/select element, jQuery just returns the attr value with no extra processing or logic. Pozdravi, G.